# why does my IBM cloud foundry app keep going offline

Tags: node.js, cloud, ibm-watson, node-red

I have a working IoT sensor sending data to the IBM cloud and I have a Node-red instance through a `.js` cloud foundry app ingesting this data and reporting on a Node-red dashboard on public facing site off the Bluemix site.
I have noticed this service stops intermittently and even a restart does not resolve it.
Logs show some errors like :

```
npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the node-red-bluemix@0.8.0 start script 'node --max-old-space-size=180 index.js --settings ./bluemix-settings.js -v'.
```

Only deleting the entire `.js` app and recreating it with node-red instance and flows work to restore operation.

I have the Lite plan (free) also I do send data every 20 seconds, but do not believe that some storage space is filling up as I do not store anything on this plan level. The longest storage object is a chart that plots the last 24 hours of data.

I want to stress that this runs for weeks and then crashes. It is becoming difficult to demo the platform.

Adding new info - responding with thanks to "hardillb":
yes, there are many more errors listed, I did not think to place most of it as they are short and less meaningful, however, here are some more from Cloud Foundry App Logs:

npm ERR! argv "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"

npm ERR! Failed at the node-red-bluemix@0.8.0 start script 'node --max-old-space-size=180 index.js --settings ./bluemix-settings.js -v'.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
 -but no file is given

npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-red-bluemix package,

it keeps repeating these (among other less meaningful ones).

@Michael - yes, this is my experience as well.  Once it gets into this mode I found that I can't even get into Node-red to even delete the flows.  Only thing that worked for me is deleting the entire Cloud Foundry App and waiting an hour or so and recreating the entire thing.  Come to think of it, maybe, next time I should delete the Cloudant instance only, where I understand it keeps the flow information.  I also agree, IBM makes it pretty tedious to know where one is headed with costs and required components.  I found a few months back that their pages seem to keep modifying so it was hard to get back into development from where I left off.  Thanks for the info about the drivers license requirement ahead for me, I think it is getting apparent to me that I need to find a different solution for my IoT cloud resource.

Comment: There must be more in the logs than just the message you've posted?

Comment: I had the same issue. About once a week Bluemix died and it took multiple restarts and sometimes emptying the flows to get it working again. Every time it failed it said it was out of memory, but this doesn't explain why it wouldn't reliably restart. I didn't find a solution and gave up. Instead I created a local Node-Red instance exposed to the internet (with a password). You could try upgrading to the (still free) next level where they give you 512MB RAM, but for me they wanted copies of my drivers license etc and it all became too hard.